# Location tracking system without using internet in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I am doing an android application to track location, I can able to get location using GPS. But have doubt is there any other option to get the location(Using Network provider) without using the internet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669749/android-asynctask-locationlistener/42671077?noredirect=1#comment72467275_42671077

check it. 
i hope its helpful to you ..!

Comment: This question doesn't make sence. You want to use network services without internet...

Comment: I mean can get location information based on my mobile network provider signal strength?

Comment: Location tracking using GSM ("http://www.google.com/glm/mmap")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you try LocationManager class in android. This class allow user to request location by gps and network provider both.

FusedLocationProvider is latest android api to get location

Answer (score -1):

When you ask Android about location you specify accuracy (Fine or Coarse). You don't know if Android will use GPS. GPS takes a lot of power, normally phone has optimization for that and try to calculate your location based on cell towers, wifi networks.

See for more details [Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)
[image]